# How to remove empty html elements and their children? (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have several posts and they generate empty html tags with empty children inside it.

How can i remove these empty html tags and their children?

```
<div class="single-book-info">
     <div>
          <p></p>
           <p></p> 
     </div>

     <p>
        <code>
           <br>
        </code>
     </p>

     <ul>
        <li>text 1</li>
        <li>text 2</li>
        <li>text 3</li>
     </ul>

<div>
```

The result that i desire is:

```
<div class="single-book-info">
     <ul>
        <li>text 1</li>
        <li>text 2</li>
        <li>text 3</li>
     </ul>

<div>
```

Comment: I've got a beautiful answer, but you've to show your attempts to get it

Comment: @Tushar now that's a good policy

Comment: put a condition over there.. if your data is blank or null or undefined , don't append it.

Comment: As the answers below are not correct(_will work for given structure only_), see [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/hyk6jLj6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may remove the necessary code for you:

> $('div.single-book-info').children('div, p').remove()

But you can also check whether if they are empty or not and then remove it.

Comment: Hi @Abhay, thanks for your answer. I was able to solve it now

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Regex, take html code as string. then remove spacing between tags and try using
 `[<[a-zA-Z\s"-=]+>]*[a-zA-Z\s0-9]+[<\/[a-zA-Z\s"-\/=]+>]*` 
this kind of regex.
better to try here https://regex101.com/ first.